# how does git submodule status pick a commit description?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule that tracks a branch. It is currently sitting at the head of the branch. But `git submodule status` comes up with a rather ugly tagging.
That commit is really the current head of the branch in question, both in the submodule and on the remote.

```
 % git submodule status
    168b1e6c54101dfa7b1b865197ab7ac660c56fcf common (tha-6-7-g168b1e6)
 % cat .gitmodules
    [submodule "common"]
    path = common
    url = git@github.com:basis-technology-corp/perceptron-segmentation-models.git
    branch = etrog-985-restructure
```

Where does the ugly string '`tha-6-7-g....`' come from? It's not a tag on the commit at the top of the branch.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: From that "ugly string", I can tell that the commit that can be referenced by the abbreviated SHA `168b1e6` is 7 commits after the tag or branch named `tha-6`. Read the manual page for `git describe` for more information. And, for the record, submodules do not track branches - they reference a specific commit.

Comment: Oh? According to the current git doc they do track branches. See the -b option to git submodule add.

Comment: `git submodule add -b foo ...` adds a pointer into your main project that points to the *current* head of the `foo` branch in your submodule, so that part is true. However, that pointer does not automatically *track* - the `foo` branch can move on, and your main project will not notice until you explicitly tell it to. The `-b branch` option is mainly there to tell it to use something other than `master`.

Comment: I didn't mean to say anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You submodule tracks a branch, yes: it is [registered in the .gitmodules file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309).

```
 git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<path>.branch
```

But the [submodule true nature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1979194/6309) doesn't change: its role is still to reference in your parent repo a *fixed* commit SHA1. That is what [`git submodule status`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) displays, and that guarantee that anyone else cloning your repo will end up with the same submodule as the one you are currently seeing.

```
git submodule status
```

> Show the status of the submodules. This will print the SHA-1 of the currently checked out commit for each submodule, along with the submodule path and the output of **[`git describe`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe)** for the SHA-1.

It is only when you do a `git submodule update --remote` that its SHA1 would change, in order to reflect the latest of a remote branch.
You would then need to commit the parent repo in order to register the new SHA1 of your submodule.

A parent repo always references a submodule SHA1, not a submodule branch.
Branch names can come and go, be renamed or deleted. That shouldn't influence the capacity of a parent repo to restore the *exact* content of a submodule.

Comment: I think I knew all that. What perplexed me, really, was the curious choice of a name for that commit. There's a tag that points to that commit, not to mention the branch label. So I guess I need to read the git describe description a lot more carefully.

Comment: @bmargulies yes, the name is entirely generated by `git describe`, following the same algorithm every time: suffixing the most recent tag that is reachable from a commit, following with the number of additional commits on top of the tagged object and the abbreviated object name of the most recent commit.